# process.start() arguments

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, process

when i do the following command into dos it will work fine

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i frame%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k video.avi
```

When I try to use the process class in c#, without the arguments, it loads ffmpeg in a console window then dissapears like usual. However, when I try to use the argument as I do above, formatted exactly the same...it doesn't work! ffmpeg still loads, however since the console window closes so fast I cannot determine what the error is :/

```
Process ffmpeg = new Process();
ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = path + "//" + "ffmpeg.exe";
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -f image2 -i frame%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k video.avi";
ffmpeg.Start();
```

Any one know why this is? Why would the command work from dos and then fail to work using c# even when the arguments are exactly the same? I've used this method before for many things and never encountered this.

Comment: Are you sure the `FileName` is correct? Shouldn't the slashes be \\ rather then //.

Comment: Use System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "ffmpeg.exe") instead. This puts the correct directory separator in the path, if one isn't already there.

Comment: ye the filename property is correct, like i said mate, the process is actually starting so the file must be found, its the arguments that are failing. I tried concatenating the string and then passing that to the arguments instead of the above, still no joy :<

Comment: if i need to convert .caf to .mp3 what shall be the arguments of the process

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try fully qualifying the filenames in the arguments - I notice you're specifying the path in the FileName part, so it's possible that the process is being started elsewhere, then not finding the arguments and causing an error.

If that works, then setting the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property on the StartInfo may be of use.

Actually, according to the link

> The WorkingDirectory property must
>   be set if UserName  and Password  are
>   provided. If the property is not set,
>   the default working directory is
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.

Comment: thank you, i set the workingdirectory property to match the same path as ffmpeg and works now

Comment: "/k \"c:\\users\\jafar.baltidynamolog\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\VideoProjectBilal\\VideoProjectBilal\\bin\\Debug\\ffmpeg.exe\" -i \"C:\\Users\\jafar.baltidynamolog\\Videos\\videos\\SampleVideo_360x240_2mb.mp4\" -i \"C:\\Users\\jafar.baltidynamolog\\Videos\\images\\2.png\" -filter_complex \"overlay=10:10\" \"c:\\users\\jafar.baltidynamolog\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\VideoProjectBilal\\VideoProjectBilal\\bin\\Debug\\Output\\SampleVideo_360x240_2mb_Output.mp4\"" I am getting problem in first space. Kindly help

Comment: So what's the answer?

Answer (score 47):

Not really a direct answer, but I'd highly recommend using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for this kind of "exploratory" C# programming.

I have the following as a saved "query" in LINQPad:

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c echo Foo && echo Bar";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Dump();
```

Feel free to adapt as needed.

Comment: don't forget to add p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().Dump(); for those (rare) apps that write to stderr as well.

Comment: @Tergiver: Except that due to buffeting, calling ReadToEnd on one stream before the other can lead to a deadlock. Sure, it's unlikely to be an issue with most programs, but I figured that, for example code, it's better to leave something out than implement it incorrectly.

Comment: I hadn't ever tried it that way, I asynchronously read both streams when redirecting a process. I see why you would give that simple example instead of a complete (asynchronous) one.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure to use full paths, e.g. not only "video.avi" but the full path to that file.

A simple trick for debugging would be to start a command window using `cmd /k <command>`instead:

```
string ffmpegPath = Path.Combine(path, "ffmpeg.exe");
string ffmpegParams = @"-f image2 -i frame%d.jpg -vcodec"
    + @" mpeg4 -b 800k C:\myFolder\video.avi"

Process ffmpeg = new Process();
ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k " + ffmpegPath + " " + ffmpegParams
ffmpeg.Start();
```

This will leave the command window open so that you can easily check the output.

Comment: @0xA3    
It really works. The ffmpeg disappear too quick to take a snapshot even I use the process.WaitForExit(10 * 1000)`10(s)`.
What does this "/k" actually mean? How did find it? Thanks.

Comment: @Stallman: `/k` means that the command window is not closed but remains open. You can get all options by calling `cmd.exe /?` on the command prompt.

Answer (score 7):

To diagnose better, you can capture the standard output and standard error streams of the external program, in order to see what output was generated and why it might not be running as expected.

Look up:

- [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx) and
- [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).

If you set each of those to true, then you can later call `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` and `process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` to get the output into string variables, which you can easily inspect under the debugger, or output to trace or your log file.

Answer (score 0):

Very edge case, but I had to use a program that worked correctly only when I specified

```
StartInfo = {..., RedirectStandardOutput = true}
```

Not specifying it would result in an error. There was not even the need to read the output afterward.