# console app parse data via arguments

Tags: c#

Ok guys, I got this far:

```
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\a\a.exe");
        procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procInfo.Arguments = "01";
        procInfo.Arguments = user_number;
        procInfo.Arguments = email;
        Process.Start(procInfo);
```

But it only passes one argument (being the last one to overwrite), how do i pass more then one argument, the args on the console is an array, this must mean i can pass more then one argument?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\a\a.exe");
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

List<string> arguments = new List<string>();
arguments.Add("01");
arguments.Add(user_number);
arguments.Add(email);

procInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", arguments);
Process.Start(procInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start(@"C:\1\a.exe", "myargument");
```

Or if the argument needs to contain a space:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\1\a.exe", "\"my argument contains a space\"");
```

Please see the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92699yzt.aspx) method's MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass in a `ProcessStartInfo` object. You can add arguments to the [Arguments property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

to use Process.Start and pass arguments you could follow the example here: [process.start() arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments)

to manipulate the arguments from your console or windows forms application just check the content of the `args` array passed to the `Main` method as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Probably, like this also using the [Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx).

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u please make yourself clear?

If you intend to pass params use the following code ...

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
procInfo.FileNmae = "example.exe"
procInfo.Arguments = "param1"
Process.Start(procInfo)
```