# How to view Process.Start() Arguments as they are passed to executable

Tags: c#, process.start

I'm trying to run a fortran executable with Process.Start and it is not working.

```
Process proc = new Process();
string args = "<C:\\file.in> C:\\file.out";
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(AppName, args);
proc.Start();
```

if I paste those arguments into a command window the application runs as expected. proc.Start() does not run as expected.

Any ideas how I can view what Start is actually passing as arguments? My gut feeling is that this is a quotes issue.

The executable launches and hangs, so I'm confident the AppName is getting passed in correctly, it looks like an argument problem.

I tried setting the WorkingDirectory to that of the input and output files as suggested in this question: [process.start() arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments) but that did not work.

Comment: are the '<' and '>' around C:\\file.in intentional? And are you using those on the command line?

Comment: Those are intentional and required and I am using those on the command line. Working with legacy fortran code is fun!

Comment: I'm pretty sure those aren't actually arguments then. '<' usually means "redirect standard input--use this file instead" and '>' means "redirect standard output--write to this file instead". Looks like your utility actually accepts input from stdin and writes to stdout.

Comment: Yep, that's how I see it, too.  The DOS prompt is going to interpret the brackets as redirect symbols.  `ProcessStartInfo` will not.

Comment: Assuming your using a 'special shell', as I'm not aware of a standard Windows cmd.exe/command.com supporting that <C:\\file.in> syntax...   You may have to find the *.exe that handles the C:\\File.in (fortran) format, and call that, passing it what it needs to process the file, etc.

Comment: The frustrating thing is I got this to work two years ago and now I can't find the code I used. Is there a way to run a straight up shell command instead of using Process.Start? I could write a little .bat file and run it. It doesn't have to be pretty :)

Comment: Why don't you setup your bat file and use this as ProcessStartInfo appname?

Comment: So, I just did a little test and App.exe <file.in >file.out works just as well as App.exe <file.in> file.out. so I'm not sure what the '<' and '>' mean. Probably redirects like you're saying, but it's hard for me to be sure because if I just launch the executable there is no console output, it's just a blind guess what I should input.

Comment: they are redirects... you will need to redirect those streams and handle it your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection with the `<` and `>` command line operators is a feature that's implemented by the command line processor.  Which is cmd.exe.  Use its /c argument to execute just a single command:

```
string args = "/c " + AppName + " < C:\\file.in > C:\\file.out";
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", args);
proc.Start();
```

Comment: I get the following: '/c' snot recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: got it working with the following: `args = "/k \"" + AppName + "\" < " + inputFileName + " > " + outputFileName;`

the /k keeps the console window open after running and was very helpful with debugging my args.

Answer (score 0):

Your **args** string is exactly what is being passed as arguments to the executable. You can double check it reading your Process [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments).

Something similar happened to me once, i.e., calling the executable from the command line worked and from code didn't, and it turned out that when called from the command line the executable was running on my PC's **[C:]** drive, and when called from code it was running on my PC's **[E:]** drive, which was full!

To check which directory your application is using to run the executable use the [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx).

Comment: I'm using full paths for the application name and for all arguments, so would it matter what the current directory is?

Comment: In my case it did because the executable I was running needed to create some temporary files and it was using the current directory to do that (instead of the [current user's temp folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)), and since it was full the executable was failing to do what it was supposed to.