# "ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'"

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-errors, clickonce

So I was writing an application that requires access to the registry.
I had not touched any build settings, wanting to get the thing working before I added the other touches, such as a description or name.
Out of the blue, I get an error that will not go away. `ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'.` Now, I hadn't touched ClickOnce in this application. All I had done was include a manifest file requesting these permissions.
My problem now is that this error will not go away, and I cannot compile my program. Any advice on what to do? (Side note: I am about to go to bed, so I will check this tomorrow afternoon).

Comment: I hate to state the obvious here, but *you added a manifest requesting `requireAdministrator` permissions* and *ClickOnce started complaining that it doesn't support `requireAdministrator`*. The problem should be extremely clear. ClickOnce is seeing the need for elevation in your manifest (which becomes part of your application). I'm not sure what more you need here...

Comment: @KenWhite: It is, however, perhaps not entirely obvious nor logical that the admin requirement in combination with click once prevents you from _compiling_ the project, not just running it - but it does.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, logic should tell you that a causal relationship exists simply by the fact that adding "requires Admin" causes it not to compile because of something to do with "requires Admin not supported", IMO. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Yup - no argument there :)

Comment: The problem is not that I want to use ClickOnce and administrator permissions, the problem is that I want to use administrator permissions, and have compiled it previously (about 10 times) with them, but this time ClickOnce is saying it is incompatible.

Comment: @KenWhite the problem is not as clear as you suggest. The problem occurs when you click the "publish" button (at least it did for me). I added the manifest and selected "requireAdministrator", after which the program worked flawlessly. Only when I clicked publish did I start getting this error, and could not clear it, until I went into the settings and disabled "ClickOnce". So the solution is not that "requireAdministrator" is not supported, but that "ClickOnce" cannot be enabled, and you cannot click "Publish" if you have "requireAdministrator" set.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

**Edit:** This comment gives a good answer, too.

> Click once appears to get enabled whenever you click "Publish", whether you want it to or not! If you are using "requireAdministrator" then it appears that you cannot use ClickOnce, and therefore cannot "Publish" your project.

---

**Original:**

Turns out that under the Security tab, "Enable ClickOnce security settings" was checked. Even though I didn't check it.
Anyway, unchecking that stopped ClickOnce giving me errors. That took a while to find...

Comment: Ah, I thought that was obvious from the error message you got ;)

Comment: What had confused me was that I didn't enable ClickOnce.

Comment: Click once appears to get enabled whenever you click "Publish", whether you want it to or not! If you are using "requireAdministrator" then it appears that you cannot use ClickOnce, and therefore cannot "Publish" your project.

Comment: What @GavinCoates says is correct. The reason is that ClickOnce applications are always installed per user in its `AppData` folder. The privilege elevation would cause a switch of the user context where the ClickOnce application is not even installed.

Comment: That is the working solution. Thank you. Before that I was checking at the beginning of the application if I am having admin rights and exit() by myself.

Comment: Please see my comment below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46456301/3393832).  This "accepted" response was on the right track, but the key was to select "Partial Trust..."

Comment: @CodeBreaker My question wasn't about using ClickOnce with elevated privileges.

Comment: @LMS - Yes, I understand.  Yesterday, I was running into the issue of having to click "Run" to give my PC the go-ahead to run the process/exe after starting the ClickOnce app by means of a separate application.  The option to either a) update the manifest, or b) un-check the box for "Enable ClickOnce security settings" did not allow the application to run without intervention.  However, my proposed solution was able to resolve the issue with no further modifications to the application settings/manifest.

Comment: @LMS - Also, in the future and before deleting an edit or comment made by another user such as myself, it would be nice if you discussed the edit/proposal to gain insight into the thought process behind why the edit was made.  Was my solution tested by anyone else before it was removed?

Comment: @CodeBreaker Don't edit other answers to draw attention to your own.

Comment: @LMS - I am sorry, but that was not my intention.  My intent was to give insight into a tested solution to the question inside of the "Accepted" answer since we all know most readers stop scrolling once they reach that point and, like in this case, have no luck.  However, since I can see that this whole situation has made some users a little... testy... I will withdraw.  Hopefully others will find value in my answer. :-)

Comment: No luck in VS2017. I will have to do what `Tyler C` in his answer says. That is adding a method to check if the user is admin, if not, call UAC.

Answer (score 58):

I know this an old question but I came here two years later so:

You can disable the ClicKOnce from the Security tab on project properites to help the issue; see below:

[image]

Comment: And when you will publish your application this checkbox will be checked again.

Comment: @dikkini, exactly! how to disable it, anyone has an answer?

Comment: @saidfagan no answer or solution for this case. I use util ULMerge to combine exe and dll files.

Comment: This works for me, doesn't matter if I have to disable the checkbox all time

Answer (score 23):

If you ever use the publishing wizard, or 'Publish Now', the click-once checkbox gets automatically selected...

Answer (score 22):

I know this is old but I stumbled across it looking for answers. In my case, I AM using the publish function and I need to keep using it. I also need access to admin capabilities. So for that reason, none of the above answers worked for me.

I ended up adding a method to the very start of my application that checks if it's being run as an administrator and if it isn't, relaunch itself as an admin. To do this, you need the following references added.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Principal;
```

Then you will need to put this somewhere that your main method has handy access to. I'm using WPF so I added it to MainWindow.xaml.cs but you can add it anywhere early on in your code. Just remember to add "static" to these methods should you need it.

```
private void AdminRelauncher()
{
    if (!IsRunAsAdmin())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        proc.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase;

        proc.Verb = "runas";

        try
        {
            Process.Start(proc);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This program must be run as an administrator! \n\n" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private bool IsRunAsAdmin()
{
    try
    {
        WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lastly, at the start of your program, add a reference to the method. In my case, I added it to MainWindow but adding it to Main works too.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AdminRelauncher(); //This is the only important line here, add it to a place it gets run early on.
}
```

Hope this helps!

**For .NET Core and .NET 5+**

If you're stumbling upon this in the 20s, this is how you would change the above to work with .NET Core and .NET 5+

The only function that needs changing is the AdminRelauncher and it should look like this instead.

```
private static void AdminRelauncher()
{
    if (!IsRunAsAdmin())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        proc.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace(".dll", ".exe");

        proc.Verb = "runas";

        try
        {
            Process.Start(proc);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This program must be run as an administrator! \n\n" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The only big changes is as someone pointed out Application isn't always available. So Environment.Exit(0) can replace it and the filename needs to replace .exe with .dll. This has been tested as of .NET 6

Comment: it start a new instance, which by define does not attach to the debugger.. (you call upon new free (unattached) instance, and close the one attached to debugger)

Comment: @deadManN very true. I got around it since I didn't need the debugger by the time I got to that point but I suppose you could run VS as admin and then the program would be launched in admin mode too. skipping the restart. I'll test that to be sure.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this, the above does in fact work.

Comment: >> The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context. error

Comment: This code only start new process but my app is console so the arguments just leave empty.

Comment: @vee for Winform projects just remove `Application.Current.Shutdown();` and use `return` to exit the `Main()` and it will works fine.

Comment: For new .net core winform applications you need: proc.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace(".dll", ".exe"); (because 1. codebase is obsolete and 2 the assembly is "xyz.dll" and not "xyz.exe")

Comment: Thanks for all the updates. I've edited the answer to include the information. For arguments you can see this post for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments

Answer (score 6):

This action can be achieved by selecting "Enable ClickOnce security settings" (since it cannot be "unchecked" during a Publish, as stated) and then by selecting "This is a partial trust application".  "Local Intranet" will be automatically selected in the drop-down menu which is perfectly fine.

Save your changes, Publish the application, done-skis. :-)[image: Security Settings Snippet]

Answer (score 6):

For those who use uncheck "Enable ClickOnce security settings" can't work, to try the method I find.

First, leave your app.manifest requestedExecutionLevel item as is:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

And then you edit your Program.cs file like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

restruct main method like:

```
    static void Main()
        {
            var wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);

            bool runAsAdmin = wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

            if (!runAsAdmin)
            {
                // It is not possible to launch a ClickOnce app as administrator directly,
                // so instead we launch the app as administrator in a new process.
                var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

                // The following properties run the new process as administrator
                processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                processInfo.Verb = "runas";

                // Start the new process
                try
                {
                    Process.Start(processInfo);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // The user did not allow the application to run as administrator
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but I don't seem to be able to start " + 
                       "this program with administrator rights!");
                }

                // Shut down the current process
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                // We are running as administrator
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
```

It works on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem s I resolve it by unchecking the "**Enable ClickOnce security settings"**
To Find this option in Visual Studio Right Click on your **Project ==>properties==>Select Security==> Enable ClickOnce security settings** (This option was already checked so I unchecked it and my problem get resolved).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code snippet for VB.NET

```
If Not New WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
            Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo With { _
                                                     .UseShellExecute = True, _
                                                     .WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory, _
                                                     .FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.CodeBase, _
                                                     .Verb = "runas"})
```

EDIT: But if you deploy in this way, some AV-Software blocks your code.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's run into this, I thought I'd contribute what ended up working for me.

Yep, the 'Enable ClickOnce security settings' option automatically gets re-checked, if you un-check it, when you do *Build > Publish* .

For me, I don't need to 'Publish' -- it's a simple, portable .exe that creates Scheduled Tasks for my users and I needed to make sure it elevated, even when logged-in as an Administrator.

So I just grabbed my latest .exe from *\bin\Release* and that's what gets deployed on my clients' systems.

Worked just as expected -- i.e. when I put it on a system w/ UAC enabled/at its highest setting, the .exe has the 'shield' on it, and when I run it, even when logged-in as an Administrator, it elevates and I get the UAC prompt.

My little task scheduler app is now able to create the task without getting an 'Access Denied' error (which previously, could only be worked-around by right-clicking the .exe and clicking Run as Administrator).

Comment: I had this exact same issue, and none of the above answers worked.  I wish they would re-work the click once security settings.  Absolutely necessary and a good feature in most cases, especially for apps being published online, however I wish there were a better option/work around for only local based publications.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your app.Manifest file and you'll see this:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

There's instructions there in the comments, but just deleting the "requireAdministrator" and insert this in is place solved the problem for me:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: OP says they require access to the registry in their application, so this is not an option.

Comment: `requireAdministrator` privilege is required to write to the registry, so this would be a requirement.

Comment: ClickOnce does not support the request execution level `asInvoke`

Comment: Some DLLs won't allow you to SET **"asInvoke"**

Answer (score -13):

just

```
Imports System.security
```

and 
U will get no error and your application will be run as admin

Comment: Simply assigning a reference to an assembly alone will not execute any code in most every case. Without more posted, this tells us nothing. This post is in regards to the requirement of administrative registry editing and more specifically deploying via the Visual Studio Publish option which generates a ClickOnce assembly. Downvoted for lack of clarity, or apparent relevence.

Comment: This... this is a no.  This will do absolutely nothing except increase your line count by 1.  Referencing an assembly with no reference to any object or calling method within that assembly will do absolutely nothing.  Like the previous comment stated.