# Publish a wpf project with request execution level 'requireAdministrator'

Tags: c#, wpf, oneclick

I want to publish my WPF application with the "*requestedExecutionLevel*" `requireAdministrator` because the application is doing **registry entries**.

As i saw in questions like this one:
["ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023998/clickonce-does-not-support-the-request-execution-level-requireadministrator/55371205#55371205), it isn't supported if you use the *click-once* publish method.

*My Question now is:* How can I still publish my project, if I use 'requireAdministrator' as request execution level? Is there any alternative to *click-once*?

Comment: You can try to use WiX and create an MSI installer for your application

Comment: Top (unaccepted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080075/9363973) on the question you linked seems to fix your issue

Comment: Sadly it didnt solve my issue. I now created an _inno_ _setup_ _script_ to publish it with the 'requireAdministrator' execution level. 
I can post it if requested.