# ClickOnce and Full Trust permissions

Tags: clickonce

I have developped an application that needs to perform administrative tasks.
But it is installed by Click Once from Internet.Therefore it is in the Internet Security Zone:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/securing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA7Cu.png)

[image]

In Visual Studio, I have enabled Full Trust Application.
[image]

We have purchased a signing certificate and signed the application.
Note: the intermediate certificate and Authority certificate are not installed on the target computers (and therefore I don't see the utility of purchasing the certifificate from this service. But it is another story).

From my understanding, I would have expected a prompt at installation time where the enduser would have given his consent to elevate the priviledges.

See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/code-access-security-for-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022
[image]

But the result is that when it is executed, it receives an access denied when performing the task (for example manipulating HKLM, creating a scheduled task,etc...).

What can I do to solve this issue? The target are remote users not always reachable (not possible to deploy by GPO or MSI Installation).

I also found this article that I have not tried yet. ["ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023998/clickonce-does-not-support-the-request-execution-level-requireadministrator)