# How to run a c# application with arguments from a batch file

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# project that takes in arguments that I'm trying to run from a bat file.  For an application that doesn't take arguments I just put the following inside a file called run.bat

```
pathname\helloworld\bin\Debug\helloworld.exe
```

What if my program takes in parameters, how do I adjust.  When is the echo of used?  any good tutorial on writing batch files? Thanks

Comment: `c#` and `c` are different languages. Please be more careful when tagging.

Comment: `"pathname\helloworld\bin\Debug\helloworld.exe" "first param" "second param"`.

Comment: Try to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I guess it is more of a bat tag than anything else :)

Comment: can you post your code for the **main** method? since it will need to accept params to work, like `string[] args` is default on console apps

Answer (score 5):

```
pathname\helloworld\bin\Debug\helloworld.exe "argument 1" "argument 2" 3

using System;
public class Demo {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        foreach(string arg in args)
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try

```
@rem turn off echo - atsign is line-level way how to do it
@echo off
@rem provided your app takes three params, this is how to pass them to exe file
pathname\helloworld\bin\Debug\helloworld.exe %1 %2 %3
```

Answer (score 0):

String arguments tend to just follow the EXE after a space. So if you have two parameters "Bob", and "is a jerk" you could write this in the .bat:

helloworld.exe Bob "is a jerk"

Bob becomes the first parameter, since it has whitespace around it. But "is a jerk" is all one because of the quotation marks. So this would be two parameters.

Your tags mention C, but I'm unclear if you actually meant you're calling this from [C, the completely seperate language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language); you seem to be just indicating you use a batch file.

Comment: I don't know why, but I kept scrolling up and down the page looking for someone named Bob...

Answer (score 0):

For your bat file, just add parameters after your exe path, like this:

```
pathname\helloworld\bin\debug\helloworld.exe param1 param2
```

Then, there's a method in your Program.cs file that looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Application.Run(args.Length > 0 ? new Main(args[0]) : new Main());
}
```

Here you can tweak the parameters that are processed and send them to your startup form.

As for the echo, that's just like a print statement, anything you want to output to the console window...