# Invalid Argument - FFMPEG

Tags: winforms, command-line, process, ffmpeg, c++-cli

similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments).
tried setting useShellExecute = false / true. it made no effect!
i just wanted to delete the original file after conversion..
when i run the following command through command prompt in windows there is no issue

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i D:\old.avi D:\new.avi && D:\del D:\old.avi
```

but if i run the same command from System::Diagnostics::Process ^process, ffmpeg shows error

> unable to find suitable format for '&&' 
>   &&: invalid aurgument

following command as an argument gives no error at System::Diagnostics::Process ^process

```
 -y -i D://old.avi D://new.avi
```

is there a way to pass 2 commands in one go? like in command prompt?

below is my code in c++/cli

```
String ^location = System::Reflection::Assembly::GetEntryAssembly()->Location;
String^ ExecutableDirectory = System::IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(location);
System::Diagnostics::Process ^process = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo^ startInfo = gcnew System::String^ Arguments = "-y -i D://old.avi D://new.mp4 && del D://old.avi"; 
System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo(ExecutableDirectory+"//ffmpeg.exe", Arguments);
startInfo->WindowStyle = System::Diagnostics::ProcessWindowStyle::Maximized;
process->StartInfo = startInfo;
process->Start();
```

Thanks