# How to generate a C# class from an XML file without using Visual Studio GUI or command line but using C# code?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to convert the contents of an XML file into a C# class. Which NuGet package can I use, and how can I use them?

My question is that I want to create a class (e.g. `Person`) class from an XML file that already contains person information.

Example for XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Person>
    <Id>3344</Id>
    <Name>Ahmed Shaikoun</Name>
    <Title>Software Engineer</Title>
    <Country>Egypt</Country>
    <Phone>0xx-xxxxxxxxx</Phone>
</Person>
```

From this XML file, I want to generate a C# class with the name of class is Person by code (not Visual Studio tips or command line) using a library from the NuGet package.

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to use your preferred search engine and search for something like "c# xml get started". There are lots of tutorials available.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605811/xmlserializer-find-element-with-name-and-attribute-value/68607179#68607179, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215415/invalidoperationexception-when-deserializing-custom-xml-lack-of-namespace, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638292/create-delete-element-on-xmlnode-c-sharp/73640395#73640395

Comment: Can you please elaborate your final goal? For what *task* you want to generate such a class from XML?

Comment: Sorry, I may have closed to quickly.  Just to confirm, you are looking to generate c# classes programmatically in runtime without using `xsd.exe`? If so, please [edit] your question to explain your requirements more explicitly.  Also, you tagged this [tag:xsd] but do you have an XSD, or just an XML file?

Comment: I have a predefined xml file and I want to write code to generate C# class based on xml file. For example, I have an xml file containing student information and I want to generate student.cs from this xml file.

Comment: Can you launch `xsd.exe` from within your c# app, e.g. as shown in [Converting XSD into .cs class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52331178)?

Comment: .NET Core, Pls!

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically a small XML sample?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need namespace "**System.Xml.Serialization**" to use class **XmlSerializer** because it has the functionality that you want that will serialize and deserialize to/from XML format to object against known type, like user defined class you will create.

Here is a quick example for you, suppose you have xml file named Person.xml and it is contains these data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Person>
    <Id>3344</Id>
    <Name>Ahmed Shaikoun</Name>
    <Title>Software Engineer</Title>
    <Country>Egypt</Country>
    <Phone>0xx-xxxxxxxxx</Phone>
</Person>
```

And you would like to create console application to just deal with this file to load data from it or to write data to it using built in functionality that support dealing with xml inside .NET framework, all you need first to define class type for this person like this:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public string Title { get; set;}
        public string Country { get; set;}
        public string Phone { get; set;}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name}, {Title}, Id: {Id}, from {Country}";
        }

    }
```

Then you will create a new class that will do the serialization/deserialization and parsing of course to load the deserialized object to memory:

```
public class XMLSerializer
    {
        public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }

        public string Serialize<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

It is pretty easy, and last you can try it by running this easy example that i made here for you:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


            XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();

            // load file
            string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Person.xml";
            string xmlInputData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            // deserialize and parse xml to person object
            Person person = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(xmlInputData);
            // display person object
            Console.WriteLine($"Serialize and display person: {person.ToString()}");

            // serialize person object to string content
            string xmlOutputData = serializer.Serialize<Person>(person);
        }
    }
```

This is all you need without dealing manually with data and also it did not require any GUI to build.

And here the full example that I prepared here:

```
namespace XMLSerialize
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


            XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();

            // load file
            string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Person.xml";
            string xmlInputData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            // deserialize and parse xml to person object
            Person person = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(xmlInputData);
            // display person object
            Console.WriteLine($"Serialize and display person: {person.ToString()}");

            // serialize person object to string content
            string xmlOutputData = serializer.Serialize<Person>(person);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public string Title { get; set;}
        public string Country { get; set;}
        public string Phone { get; set;}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name}, {Title}, Id: {Id}, from {Country}";
        }

    }
    public class XMLSerializer
    {
        public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }

        public string Serialize<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XmlSerializer** is defined in Assembly **System.Xml.XmlSerializer**, it is working with .NET 7 too.

I hope my little answer helping you to do this task.
Thank you

Comment: You are defining the person class first, but my question is that I want to create a person class from an XML file that already contains person information.

Comment: @ThaiQuocToanK15HCM - your question was not clear then.  See [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203540/3744182).

Comment: All of answers here that are using visual studio tips or command line to generate class, but I want to generate class in C# code using libraries in Nuget package. Do you have any idea for this? Thanks!

Comment: Dear @ThaiQuocToanK15HCM, i think your question did not explain your need very well, but any way, if i understand your comment here clearly, then the answer is very simple too, use Reflection to this, you will dealing with classes like System.Type and System.Reflection.AssemblyName and System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder and more to do this easilly, i think if you do some quick search you will locate a lot of examples doing this on the internet, for instance you can see this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/

Thanks