# How to Start and Fire a Command

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, process

It is supposed to be easy, but I can't get it work.

When I run the following command inside cmd, it works perfectly fine. When I run the command inside the `c#` code, it won't do anything (no exception has been thrown either).

Here is the command I'm using (which works perfectly fine when using directly on `cmd.exe`):

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin && SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword&& pg_restore.exe -U username -d dbname C:\file\to\dump\my.dump
```

Here is what I'm trying to do in `c#` (not working):

```
var arg = @"cd %ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin && SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword&& pg_restore.exe -U username -d dbname C:\file\to\dump\my.dump";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", arg);
```

Am I missing something? I found a lot of posts concerning `c#` starting a process, but nothing solved my problem. I also tried to start the process with `StartInfo` and added the Properties like `Arguments`, `FileName`, etc., but it did not work either.

Be aware, the question [process.start() arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments) is not the same - in my case, I neet to set the `system variable (SET PGPASSWORD)`, since `pg_restore` has no password argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [process.start() arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments), you may need to set the `WorkingDirectory`?

Comment: You don't need `cmd` for starters. The application you want to run is `pg_restore`, not `cmd`.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I tryed it with WorkingDirectory, it did not work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - No, when I start pg_restore, I cannot set the password argument, that's why i need to set the attribute from cmd

Comment: @gala_m you *don't* need to do that, ProcessStartInfo allows you to set environment variables. `cmd` is nothing more than the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix your argument string with `/c` so that cmd knows that you're telling it what to do:

```cs
var arg = @"/c cd %ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin && SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword&& pg_restore.exe -U username -d dbname C:\file\to\dump\my.dump";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", arg);
```

Comment: Does the user even need the `/c`? Why not just call it directly?

Comment: you made my day! Thank you @Albie - what is /c standing for? ITS WORKING, thank you!

Comment: @gala_m there's no reason to open a console to run another process, not even to pass environment variables

Answer (score 1):

`cmd` is just the console, it isn't needed to start another process.

The application you want to run is `pg_restore.exe` in the `%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin` folder. You can pass environment variables through [ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables?view=netframework-4.8) dictionary. I'm not sure if the ProcessStartInfo constructor expands environment variables. You can use [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netframework-4.8) to ensure the path is correct :

```
var binFolder=@"%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin\";
var fullPath=Path.Combine(binFolder,"pg_restore.exe");
var arguments=@"-U username -d dbname C:\file\to\dump\my.dump";

var fullPath=Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathToRestore);
var startInfo=new ProcessStartInfo(fullPath,arguments) {
       UseShellExecute =false,
       //Need this to read the output if needed
       RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       //Set if needed
       WorkingDirectory = binFolder
};
startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"]=password;

var process=Process.Start(startInfo);

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: This is not working for me either - Shouldn't `WorkingDirectory` be the bin folder where the .exe is placed anyways? I copied your code and changed the paths - it did nothing, i just ran but did not effect a thing.

Comment: @gala_m only if `pg_restore.exe` needs access to other files in the `bin` folder. The full path to the executable is already provided in the `fullPath` variable. I changed the code to use the bin folder as the working directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
var command = "SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword && pg_restore.exe";
var param = "-U username -d dbname C:\file\to\dump\my.dump";
var process = new Process();
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, param)
            {
                WorkingDirectory = @"%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin"
            };
process.StartInfo = processInfo;
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer for example, where they went wrong and why. It doesn't have to be a full, novel-like solution that details every step, only enough to give sight one needs in order to realize your solution.

Comment: This is not working, i get the exception "No process is associated with this object.'"